# Issues with CSS3 transition and transform elements & code inspect oddity

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to use some CSS3 transition/transform effects for a menu and I have been noticing some odd behaviors while I was debugging.

Along with the CSS3 transitions and transform, I am using a simple jQuery function to capture a click and add a transition delay.

```html
<button class="menu">
      Show Navigation
    </button>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {


      $(".menu").click(function() {
        $("body").toggleClass("menu-active");
        $(".navigation li").each(function(index) {
          $(this).css({
            'transition-delay': (.25 * index) + 's'
          });
        });
      });

    });
```

```css
    .navigation {
      display: none;
      margin: 100px 0 0 0;
    }

    .navigation li {
      margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(7.5%, 0, 0);
    }

    .menu-active .navigation li {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      transition: transform 0.3s ease 0.15s, opacity 0.3s ease 0.15s;
    }

    .navigation li a {
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 24px;
    }

    .menu-active .navigation {
      display: block;
    }
```

Here is the jsfiddle for my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/zeropsi/8vprw45y/

Now, as you can see, the transition/transform effects do not appear when you click the button, however, if you inspect the element (i'm using Chrome) and click on the list element, you can see the transition occur.

Any thoughts around what may be causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your css. `display: none` disables animation.

```css
.navigation {
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
}
/* ... */
.menu-active .navigation {
  opacity: 1;
}
```